# Can PhpStorm generate a PHPUnit test class in a different default directory?

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, php-7

In the context menu for a particular class, there is the option to create a new "PHPUnit Test" for that class. However, when I click on it, it defaults to the same directory as the class under test and also uses the same namespace.

When I want to create a test class for  `src/Foo/Foo.php` with namespace `\MyApp\Foo`, I want it to default to `test/Foo/FooTest.php` with the default namespace `\MyAppTest\Foo`. I've marked the directories as a source root and tests root within PhpStorm, but the generated file shows the incorrect defaults.

Comment: There is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38128 issue - would be great if you could add a comment there that would describe your issue. Seems to be related.